# Listing of all users in the users collection not working first time with meteor js

Tags: meteor

I am having the issue with listing all the user's  in the users collection. When I take the listing page, only the currently logged in user's details are shown. But all users are getting listed once the page is refreshed and there on its fine.

On Server side, I have the following publish code

```
Meteor.publish("userList", function() {

    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({
        _id: this.userId
    });


    if (Roles.userIsInRole(user, ["admin"])) {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {
            fields: {
                profile_name: 1,
                emails: 1,
                roles: 1,
                contact_info: 1
            }
        });
    }

    this.stop();
    return;
});
```

On Client side,

```
Meteor.subscribe('userList');
```

In the Template js file, I make the following call,

```
Meteor.users.find();
```

Please help me out with this issue. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like a race condition with the subscription (it runs before the user is logged in). I'd recommend putting your subscription inside of an [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun):

```js
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Meteor.subscribe('userList');
  }
});
```

This has the additional benefit of not starting your subscription before the user is logged in (saves resources).

BTW, I can't think of a reason why you'd need the `this.stop()` and the end of your publish function.

Comment: That was helpful. One more thing, I want to get the list which doesn't include the logged in user. So I tried, 

     Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: this.userId}}, {
            fields: {
                profile_name: 1,
                emails: 1,
                roles: 1,
                contact_info: 1
            }
        });

but its not working. Any suggestions regarding this ?

Comment: Do you mean: "How do I publish all users except the current user?", or do you mean "What client-side query do I use in my templates to display a list of users who are not the current user?"

Comment: I have a user listing page. I want all users except the one who's logged in. With the current publish code, am getting all users including the logged in user, even with the above modification in the query.

Comment: There are a lot of concepts here that are going to be hard to cover in a comment. PS, I'd recommend reading [the meteor book](http://www.discovermeteor.com/). So the goal of the publishers are to send a subset of the database to the client - not to send exactly the subset that matches any one query on the client. You are not allowed to avoid publishing the current user to the client, so you have more data than you need, and that's okay. On the client you can do a query like `Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.usersId()}});` to get the list you want. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you David. Responses were very helpful.