# Publishing all Meteor.users doesn't work

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to publish all the usernames to the clients, even if not signed in. For that, on the server I have:

```
Meteor.publish("users", function() { 
   return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields : { username : 1 } });
});
```

And on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("users");
```

However, when I try to access the Meteor.users collection, I find nothing there.

(This is essentially the same as the question here: [Listing of all users in the users collection not working first time with meteor js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945225/listing-of-all-users-in-the-users-collection-not-working-first-time-with-meteor), only without checking the roles for admin first. Still doesn't seem to work..)

I'm probably missing something silly..

Comment: Where do you try to access this cursor, on the client?

Comment: Are you sure that the subscription is ready when you are accessing the data?

Comment: @stubailo should it matter? Shouldn't the reactive model update my data when it is ready?

Comment: Then perhaps you're doing something wrong in the template where you're showing all the users.

Comment: @PeppeL-G Nothing to do with the template. count() returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

I find the same issue, and after doing a research i find [this](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) package, i think it may should help you.

Take a look and hope it help you

**Update**

First move the subscription to the `/lib` folder, just to make sure its the first thing meteor do when start, also change a little bit the subscription like this on the `/lib`, folder.

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  if (!Meteor.user()) {
    console.log("sorry you need to be logged in to subscribe this collection")
   }else{
    Meteor.subscribe('users');
   }
 } 
});
```

For better security we just subscribe to the users collection when the client its logged in

Comment: If you think this is a bug, please create a reproducible project and [create an issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/new) about it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad that inst a bug its a "familiar issue"

Comment: Why did you use Meteor.autorun?

Answer (score 1):

This code outputs all the usernames to the clients, even if not signed in (in this case on /users page):

server/publications.js:

```
Meteor.publish("userlist", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({},{fields:{username:1}});
});
```

client/users_list.js:

```
Template.usersList.helpers({
    users: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    }
});
```

client/users_list.html:

```
<template name="usersList">
      {{#each users}}
        {{username}}
      {{/each}}
</template>
```

lib/router.js (using iron:router package):

```
Router.route('/users', {
    name: 'usersList',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe("userlist");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.